# r intersect two list elementwise

Tags: r, lapply

I have two lists of integer vectors named `GroundStates` (length=3) and `naMat` (length=4).
I want to intersect the lists elementwise, meaning I want the intersect of each vector in `GroundStates` with each vector in `naMat`.

I tried using a nested `lapply()`:

```
GS_conut_EP<-lapply(1:3, function(i) intersect((GroundStates[i]),lapply(1:4,function(x) as.integer(unlist(naMat[x])))))
```

this produced a list of length 3, but all three elements were empty.

I also tried using `Reduce()`:

```
GS_conut_EP<-Reduce(intersect, c(GroundStates,naMat))
```

Which also produced an empty vector.

I do know that there are intersects between the lists, becuase I tried calling `unlist()` on one vector in each list and intersecting them.

Of course, I can always use a for loop, but I was wondering if there isn't a more elegent way to this?

Comment: Do you mean something like `intersect(unlist(GroundStates), unlist(naMat))`?

Comment: Can you post a sample data set? It definitely looks like you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your output as a list of lists, you can do something like:

```
lapply(GroundStates, function(x) lapply(naMat, function(y) intersect(x,y)))
```

Comment: @user1614062 note that this will have "duplicates", i.e., sets `L[[i]][[j]]` and `L[[j]][[i]]` (where `L <- lapply(...)`) will be the same. If this is an issue, please tell and I'll post a fix.

Comment: @ Ferdinand.kraft Thanks for telling me this. Though I see no duplicates in the output

Comment: @user1614062 they may be out of order, but they will be there, since `intersect(x,y)` and `intersect(y,x)` return the same set.